# problem connecting to remote mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache

If I open up a cmd shell and run

```
>mysql --host=12.34.56.78 --port=1234 --user=myuser --password=mypassword mydb
```

I can successfully connect to the remote mysql database.

But if I create a php page on my localhost containing

```
<?php
$hostname = "12.34.56.78:1234";
$username = "myuser";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname   = "mydb";
$connect = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die ("Error: could not connect to database");
?>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: could not connect to database
```

Can anyone explain what might be causing the problem here?

```
mysql_error() => mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication
```

Comment: use `$connect = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die ("Error: could not connect to database (".mysql_error());` and give results here

Comment: I assume --password=mypasword and $password = "mypassword" is a simple typo, yes?

Comment: Please enable error reporting and post the error the mysql_connect function gives.

Comment: Could you output the function mysql_error() in your die()? That would give the reason mysql can't be connected to.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/old-client.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth problems are a known issue with PHP 5.3 and older versions of MySQL. Check this:

http://www.bitshop.com/Blogs/tabid/95/EntryId/67/PHP-mysqlnd-cannot-connect-to-MySQL-4-1-using-old-authentication.aspx

Answer (score 0):

maybe in your php.ini parameter sql.safe_mode is "1"?

```
sql.safe_mode boolean
```

If turned on, database connect functions that specify default values will use those values in place of supplied arguments. For default values see connect function documentation for the relevant database.