# PHP connection to remote MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I try to connect through the shell of the local machine at the remote MySQL server I can successfully connect:

```
> mysql -h remotehost -u myuser -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```

But when I try to connect through a PHP script using

```
$serverName = "remotehost"; // here I put the actual IP address
$userName = "myuser";
$passCode = "actualpassword";
mysql_connect($serverName,$userName,$passCode);
```

I get the following error

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

The remote MySQL server version is 5.1.52 and the PHP version in the local machine is 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4

I found a similar question but the answer does not solve my problem:
[problem connecting to remote mysql database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445293/problem-connecting-to-remote-mysql-database-using-php)

I'd really appreciate some help!

**EDIT**:

**The output of** `php -i | grep "mysql"`

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,

/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,

/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini

mysql

MYSQL_SOCKET => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

MYSQL_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include/mysql

MYSQL_LIBS => -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient_r

mysql.allow_local_infile => On => On

mysql.allow_persistent => On => On

mysql.connect_timeout => 60 => 60

mysql.default_host => no value => no value

mysql.default_password => no value => no value

mysql.default_port => no value => no value

mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

mysql.default_user => no value => no value

mysql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited

mysql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited

mysql.trace_mode => Off => Off

mysqli

MYSQLI_SOCKET => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On

mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On

mysqli.default_host => no value => no value

mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306

mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value

mysqli.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

mysqli.default_user => no value => no value

mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited

mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited

mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off

PDO drivers => mysql

pdo_mysql

pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: You say its a remote server but the error says localhost. Which is it?

Comment: this is the error I get in the local machine when I try to connect to the remote server

Comment: myuser is only allowed to login from localhost. You need to change/add a user that allows your host.

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: @ADyson mysql_ was used just for illustration purposes

Comment: @Vasilis Ok, good, but we weren't to know that. I see lots of genuine code on here where people are writing new software using it, which is very worrying. I can only assume people are unwittingly following very out-of-date tutorials or something.

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding, confirm the $serverName variable really is a remote address, either a hostname or an IP address. Then...

- Be sure you have enabled remote access on the SQL server. See this link for details: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html
- Ensure that you have told the remote MySQL server to allow the local IP address' access.
- Ensure the username and password are correct.

Comment: I try to ensure the above by trying to connect through the shell which succeeds

Answer (score 0):

Did you post actual code? If so, you forgot to enclose the strings in quotes:

```
$serverName = "remotehost"; // here I put the actual IP address
$userName   = "myuser";
$passCode   = "actualpassword";
mysql_connect($serverName,$userName,$passCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow remote access to the mySQL(on the server where you have mySQL db). If you are using CPanel or Plesk, you can do it in the control panel. I had this problem, apparently mySQL default config is to only allow localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant access for that user to be accessible by your server's IP address.  Often times the MySQL user is locked down to the localhost.

A quick way to do this would be to look at the table `mysql.users` and see if that user is locked down to the localhost.

There are many nice GUIs that can help with adding hosts, but the most manual way possible would be to add another row to the DB.  You could change the host to '%' to test but that opens things up and is less secure.

Comment: how is it possible to do that?

Comment: I just edited my response.  Are you using a particular GUI, phpMyAdmin, or just manually using MySQL CLI?

Comment: I'm using the phpmyadmin gui, I specify the user host as % but it doesn't work. I can connect remotely from the mysql shell command, but not from php

Comment: can you post your MySQL runtime config for php, either via `phpinfo` or from the command line `php -i | grep "mysql"`

Comment: I added the output to my question!

Answer (score 0):

Use `SHOW GRANTS` to see if the user you are trying to login with has permission to connect from the web server's IP or domain name.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*6381FFD48B21F7ED17AE12AF4F8BE4458F4B0AC7' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Use the `GRANT` command to give remote access to your *web user*, so to speak. Something like this.

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT ON database.table TO 'myuser'@'web_server_IP_or_domain_name' IDENTIFIED BY 'actualPassword';
```

Reference the MySQL 5.1 manual for exact syntax. [MySQL 5.1 Manual: GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)